# Jboss wilfly modules - how to reuse library registered as module(s)

Tags: jar, module, jboss, reusability

My whole point of asking this question is to clean up some libraries from my WAR/EAR deployments.

I'm using wildfly 15 right now and I have my own library (eg# module name "com.test.mathfinder" jar file name mathfinder.jar) as a module. My deployment structure is EAR->WAR. Since my jar file is registered/exposed as a module, at my WAR level, inside WEB-INF I'm including jboss-deployment-structure.xml which describes about dependencies that my war file has. Here I'm adding the module name ("com.test.mathfinder) as a dependency which I included as a module. Here the question is, should I include that jar file again my WEB-INF\lib ?

All I'am trying to achieve here is to avoid jar files from my WEB-INF\lib folder which are already published as a modules by Jboss. for example, in my wildfly folder jackson is core jar is available as a module, C:\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\main\jackson-core-2.4.1.jar

but the same jackson-core-2.4.1.jar file is also being shipped along with in my WAR file. Can we just reuse the same jar by including the dependency in jboss-deployment-structure.xml file and stop shipping this redundant file?

Answer (score 2):

> Can we just reuse the same jar by including the dependency in
>   jboss-deployment-structure.xml file and stop shipping this redundant
>   file?

To answer your question in one word is **"YES"**.

If the dependencies required by your application is provided by JBoss then you do not need to add these dependencies at runtime (i.e. not required to add in `lib` folder). To provide these dependencies runtime to your application, you can add module dependency in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file.

> Here I'm adding the module name ("com.test.mathfinder) as a dependency
>   which I included as a module. Here the question is, should I include
>   that jar file again my WEB-INF\lib ?

If you are adding module dependency in jboss deployment structure, you do not need to add this dependency in WEB-INF\lib folder of your war/ear.

But there is a **drawback** of the above method i.e. If your application is getting migrated from JBoss to any other server, dependencies mentioned in jboss-deployment-structure will not be available to the application on the new server. You need to add these dependencies again in your `lib` folder.